# KendoAutoComplete issue in chrome only

Tags: jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufabs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82fzE.png)

when i type any user name then it showing this above error.but when we open it in firefox and Internet Explorer it works fine. Below is my code

```
 function GetActiveEmployeeNames() {
        //debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "VerveWall.aspx/GetActiveEmployeeNames",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                OnSucceeded(response.d, null, null);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

it invoke below function

```
 var source = [];
    function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
        //debugger;
        //source = "";
        if (result.length > 0) {
            if (source.length < 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                    source.push({
                        "empId": result[i].Id,
                        "employeeName": result[i].Employee_Name,
                        "firstName": result[i].FirstName,
                        "middleName": result[i].MiddleName,
                        "lastName": result[i].LastName,
                        "photographFileName": result[i].PhotographFileName
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        bindPost();            
    }
```

and it invoke bindPost function

```
  function bindPost() {
        //debugger;
        var highlight_users = new Array();
        $("#<%=txtPostMessage.ClientID%>").kendoAutoComplete({
            separator: " ",
            filter: "contains",
            dataTextField: "employeeName",
            dataSource: source,
            minLength: 3,
            placeholder: "What's on your mind...",
            template: '<img src="upload/Photograph/${data.photographFileName}" width=30 height=30/>&nbsp;${data.employeeName}',
            height: 370,
            select: function (data) {
                tagging_users.push(data.empId);
                highlight_users.push(data.firstName);
                highlight_users.push(data.lastName);

                $("#<%=txtPostMessage.ClientID%>").highlightTextarea('enable');
                jQuery("#<%=txtPostMessage.ClientID%>").highlightTextarea({
                    words: highlight_users,
                    color: "#aacccc"
                });
            }

        }).data("kendoAutoComplete");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of kendo do you use? 
If newer then from year 2012, you will need update your jQuery
See [Kendo UI prerequisites](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites)

Comment: Kendo UI v2011.3.1413

Comment: please vote my question if u like so that i can gain reputation